# QTreeWidget Expanding individual Items from memory in C++

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I have a Qt `QTreeWidget` and I am trying to save the state of which header items were expanded so that when I refresh my tree with new information it can re expand the items that were previously expanded.

Each time an `itemExpanded` or `itemCollapsed` `signal` is emitted I catch it in a `slot` and save to a member `boolean` for that particular item to represent whether expanded is now `true` or `false`. This is my memory.

When refreshing the tree I clear the tree completely using

```
clear();
```

Next I collapse all the headers using

```
collapseAll();
```

Now I want to restore which items were expanded and set them to expanded using each `boolean` I have that represents whether the item was previously expanded or collapsed using

```
expandItem();
```

I'm not particularly sure how to get the index of the item from my `boolean` alone.

I would of thought that

```
indexOfTopLevelItem(0);
```

Would give me the index of my `toplevelitem` at position 0 and then using my `boolean` associated with position 0 I could then decide whether to expand the item?

This also doesn't solve my problem of wanting to do it to each 'boolean' I have representing each item in the tree.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [`itemExpanded()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#itemExpanded) signal's parameter is a pointer to [`QTreeWidgetItem`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html). With a pointer to `QTreeWidgetItem`, you can call [`QTreeWidget::indexOfTopLevelItem`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#indexOfTopLevelItem), which will return the index of the expanded item. If you just store it with your boolean, you should have enough information to restore the items' state after the content has been updated.